# How to make a small php link "spider" and extract data?

Tags: php, regex, dom, domdocument

I want to spider a simple white website that has lot's of html links that represent
a phone number' name and address. From each page i want to extract the exact 3 fields
that are between the 3 TD's such as:

```
    <div id="idTabResults2" align="center">
        <TABLE border='1'>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Adress</th><th>Phone number</th></tr>
    <TR>
          <TD>Joe</TD><TD>New York</TD><TD>555999</TD></TR>
    </TABLE>

    </div>
```

So in the example above i would get "Joe", "New York" & 555999.
I'm using php and mysql later to insert every result to my DB.
Can someone point me to the right direction on how to go about this?

Comment: You probably want an HTML parser, not a regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a faster (and simpler) way than PeeHaa's solution:

- Retrieve the page using `file_get_contents()`
- Parse it with [Simple DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

For instance:

```
<?php
require("simple_html_dom.php");
$data = file_get_contents(YOUR_PAGE_HERE);
$html = str_get_html($data);
$tds = $html->find('td');

foreach ($tds as $td) {
  // Do something
}
?>
```

Comment: And to iterate for each link?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just make your loop begin after `require` and end after the `foreach` curly bracket.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the page content using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Once you have the content you can parse it with PHP's [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Do not attempt to try and parse it using regex. God will kill a kitten just for that.

Comment: So how can i parse using the DOM? really new to that one.